# "Can not find source" in Eclipse CDT in UBUNTU 14.10

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu

My problem is that I try to debug this simple Hello World Program in `Eclipse LUNA CDT` and `UBUNTU 14.10` but get the error- can't find source at `/build/buildd/glibc-2.19/stdio-common/printf.c`. My Code is

```
# include <stdio.h>`
int main()`
{
   printf("\n Hello World!!");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see two ` at  ends of lines in your code. If these characters are really parts of your code, it is wrong...Otherwise, this piece of code seems correct.

Comment: There is not enough information regarding your environment. First of all, have you created an Eclipse project and are you able to build your project from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

First remove the two **'** in your program (first and second line).Before all of this remember to select the " linux gcc " compiler while creating your project file. Then create your source file and give   **.c** extension